# If I use foreign key in room, will it save data in its table or separate table?

Tags: java, android, android-room, androidx

For example, I have two entities:

```
@Entity
class A
long made;
long modi;

@Entity
class B extands A
String name;
```

In this case, will this data be written in Room as single Table or separately?

And another example:

```
@Entity
Class A
long made;

@Entity
Class B
String name;

@Embedded Class A
```

In this case - in single table? or separately?

I guess if I use Foreign Key, then it means I will take out data from another table.
But I want data to be written in separate tables, but retrieve them into single ArrayList<<'type'>>.
Because I want to make a single RecyclerView for all datas.

For example, Zoo:

- Animal datas:names, ethnic things, color, age........
- Personal datas: who works therein like names, age, gender, hair color...........
- Zoo's assets: like cars, buildings, lands..........

I want to show all of them into single RecyclerView, 
and I use all 3 data in different ArrayList<'Animals'>, ArrayList<'Persons'>, ArrayList<'Assets'>.
I want compare them with made date, modified date and name and then make another ArrayList<'type'>, which will indicate which data I should use from those 3 lists in order and RecyclerView.Adapter will use data from those 3 different lists in made order or modified order or name order.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, or what your tables look like, but a column that is a foreign key to another table is also a column in that table, and an index in both tables, so it is stored four times.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my ignorance of English,but i hope you could understand what i am trying to anwser.

Your question is the entity for the item is not a single class?

if it is,use a Field in single class as a tag, it not well be work?